# gpg-agent tries to use a non-existent ssh key

Tags: ssh, gpg-agent

I once did an `ssh-add` on an ssh key, let’s call it `foo`. Then I removed `foo` and added another key `foobar` for the same devices.

Now gpg-agent always queries for `foo` first, even though it doesn’t exist. I am aware of `ssh-add -d`, but `ssh-add -d foo` does nothing.

How can I remove `foo` from gpg-agent?

Answer (score 1):

According to this question on Stack-overflow: "[How to remove a ssh key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464930/how-to-remove-a-ssh-key)", the `ssh-add -d/-D` command is not removing the keys properly from the `ssh` keyring.

Summarizing the previously cited question, a few ways to workaround would be to:

- Do `ssh-add -D` to delete all your manually added keys. This also locks the automatically added keys.
- Or, navigate to your `~/.ssh` folder and move all your key files except the one you want to identify with into a separate folder called backup.

Comment: You are right, this is a duplicate of the SO question. So if you change your answer to only link to that, I will accept it.

Comment: Well, I kept the link but I do not like "link-only" answer, so I tried to summarize what you should do.